# Obtener últimos 12 meses de cuantos clientes han contactado, chart.js AJAX

Tags: jquery, laravel, chart.js

Buenas tardes de Domingo. Estoy generando una consulta a la base de datos con AJAX, para obtener los últimos 12 meses cuantos clientes han contactado en cada mes. Normalmente esto lo hago con PHP y no tengo estos problemas, pero al necesitar cambiar de opción desde el selector que activa el AJAX lo estoy haciendo con jquery.

**Primero obtengo las promociones que tengo en mi web:**

```
public function contactos()
    {
        $contactos = Campana::get();
        //dd($contactos);
        return view('admin.contactos')->with(['contactos' => $contactos]);
    }
```

**Luego los cargo en un select y según la selección mando la información por ajax al controlador**

```
<select class="form-control selectAJAX" id="campana" onchange="muestraMas();">
         <option value="99">Todos</option>
      @foreach ($contactos as $item)
         <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

**Obtengo la id de la campaña y la mando por ajax**

```
window.onload = function() {
    muestraMas();
  };

  let myChart2;
  function muestraMas(){
    var campana=document.getElementById('campana').value;
    var url = '/selectCampana';
    $.ajax({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      data: {'campana': campana},
            beforeSend: function(){
              //$("#laGrafica").html("<div id='loader'></div>")
            },
            success: function (resultado){
                var grpTecnologia=document.getElementById("contactos");
                var tecno=grpTecnologia.getContext("2d");
                if (myChart2) {
                  myChart2.destroy();
                }
                myChart2 = new Chart(tecno, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: [ resultado.result ] ,
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Equipos',
                    data: [ resultado.result ],
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(55 162 235 / 70%)",
                    borderColor: "rgb(55 162 235 / 100%)",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    borderSkipped: false,
                  }]
                },
              });
                
            },
    });
  }
```

**En mi controlador**:
Según la id que obtengo cargo sus registros

```
public function selectCampana(Request $request)
    {
        $result = [];
        $fecha = new DateTime("now");
        $fecha->modify('first day');
        $fecha->modify('-11 months');
        $fecha_inicio = (new DateTime('now'))->modify('first day')->modify('-11 months')->format('Y-m-d');
        $fecha_fin = (new DateTime('now'))->modify('last day')->format('Y-m-d');
        for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
            $result[$fecha->format('Y-M')] = 0;
            $fecha->modify('+1 month');
        }

        $data = Contactos::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, created_at'))
                    ->where('id', $request->campana)
                    /*->whereBetween('created_at', [$fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin])*/
                    ->groupBy('created_at')->get();

        foreach($data as $t) {
            $fechas = date('Y-M', strtotime($t->created_at));
            if (isset($result[$fechas]) === true) {
                $result[$fechas] += $t->total;
            } else {
                $result[$fechas] = $t->total;
            }
        }

        //dd($result);
        return compact('result');
    }
```

Si hago un `dd($result);` obtengo esto:

```
array:12 [
  "2020-Aug" => 0
  "2020-Sep" => 0
  "2020-Oct" => 0
  "2020-Nov" => 0
  "2020-Dec" => 0
  "2021-Jan" => 0
  "2021-Feb" => 0
  "2021-Mar" => 0
  "2021-Apr" => 0
  "2021-May" => 0
  "2021-Jun" => 0
  "2021-Jul" => 1
]
```

Pero al recibirlo por ajax hago un `console.log(resultado.result);` y obtengo esto:

```
2020-Aug: 0
2020-Dec: 0
2020-Nov: 0
2020-Oct: 0
2020-Sep: 0
2021-Apr: 0
2021-Feb: 0
2021-Jan: 0
2021-Jul: 1
2021-Jun: 0
2021-Mar: 0
2021-May: 0
```

Que ya de por si me los esta ordenando mal, pero además de eso no se como hacer para que me ponga los valores en la gráfica, estoy probando así:

`labels: [ resultado.result ] ,` y `data: [ resultado.result ],` pero nada sin éxito.

Comment: Lo mas seguro es que el problema este en tu consulta, pero primero que nada deberías de asegurarte de que, `$request->campana` no este llegando vació

Comment: Por que `$request->campana` @Josbert no lo entiendo?

Comment: Si, `$request->campana` de casualidad esta llegando como `null` esto no traerá nada de la consulta, o no la traerá como deberia es lo primero que tienes que ver

Comment: Ya que no esta arrojando ningún error, lo mejor es revisar paso por paso :D

Comment: Ahora entendi! ok pero eso si funciona bien. Mi problema es el hecho de no saber como implantarlo en la gráfica @Josbert

Comment: Ahmm ¿si esta trayendo los resultados correctos? perfecto, ¿tu duda es con **Chart.js**?

Comment: ¿Que versión usas de **Chart.js**?

Comment: La 3.4.1 es la que estoy utilizando. En otro proyecto también la estoy usando pero con php y funciona correcto @Josbert

Comment: Bien no hay problema, ya te doy una respuesta que te puede funcionar :D

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevo toda la tarde con ello!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127644/discussion-between-josbert-and-miguel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, suponiendo que lo que te trae la petición **ajax** sea un **objeto** como se muestra en tu pregunta, puedes hacer lo siguiente para crear las **etiquetas** y **valores** de *Chart.js*:

```js
// Obtenemos los resultados de la petición
// ...
success: function (resultado){
    var grpTecnologia=document.getElementById("contactos");
    var tecno=grpTecnologia.getContext("2d");
    if (myChart2) {
        myChart2.destroy();
    }
    
    myChart2 = new Chart(tecno, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {

        // Pasamos las claves del objeto a un Array
        labels: Object.keys(resultado.result),

        datasets: [{
            label: 'Equipos',

            // Pasamos los valores del objeto a un Array
            data: Object.values(resultado.result),

            backgroundColor: "rgb(55 162 235 / 70%)",
            borderColor: "rgb(55 162 235 / 100%)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderSkipped: false,
        }]
      },
  });
                
},
```

Esto deberia funcionar muy bien para ti, usando los métodos [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) y [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) de **Javascript**

---

##### Nota:

Asegúrate de que la el parámetro `resultado.result` sea un **objeto** y no un un **JSON**

Comment: Hola @Josbert ! Funciona perfecto, pero ahora por el motivo que sea no cuenta ningún registro como antes!

Comment: Muy bien!.. jeje ¿no has cambiado nada?

Comment: Bueno fui haciendo otras cosas, me toca revisar por que trae todo ceros todos los meses, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Llevare esto al chat

Comment: recomiendo que lo debvuelva como json y luego lo convierta en objeto XD

Comment: Hola @Josbert te vas a reir un rato, resulta que no vi que el fragmento de código para los labels y los datas era diferente y no puse este `Object.values(resultado.result)` ahora ya funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Miguel Perfecto me alegra jeje, por nada